# Is Nothing type mismatch VB6

Tags: vb6

I tried everything, but everything gives me type mismatch:

```
Type UserType
...
End Type

Dim SomeArray() As UserType
...
If SomeArray() Is Nothing Then <do smth>
If SomeArray() Is Empty Then <do smth>
If SomeArray Is Nothing Then <do smth>
If SomeArray Is Empty Then <do smth>
```

I do want to know when in my array of user-defined type is no elements! Because I don't want to use additional variables if I can use VB6 possibilities.

I'll use

```
Erase SomeArray
```

when its size = 1 (`UBound(SomeArray) = 1`) and i want to remove last element.

Answer (score 2):

VB6 "Is Nothing" applies to objects, not [VB6 arrays](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-vb6-arrays-advanced).

"Ubound(myarray)", or "Ubound - LBound" is the way to determine an array's current length in VB6.

FYI,  using a VB6 [Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231021%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) might be a much better for you.

Comment: Collection does not work with user's types. It writes something like "you're coerced bastard suck my make! link yorself in public pre-compiled module, late-bound scum!". The only thing I understand - "scum". It's very offensively.
More than this! I cannot even add simple String into Collection! O_O

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I found an arse-way to solve this problem from VBForums "VB6 - Returning/Detecting Empty Arrays". B)

(L/UBound doesn't work with empty arrays - it returns out of range subscript. ;) )

So...

```
Private Declare Function ArrPtr Lib "msvbvm60" Alias "VarPtr" (Ptr() As Any) As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (lpvDest As Any, lpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)

Public Function Peek(ByVal lPtr As Long) As Long
    Call CopyMemory(Peek, ByVal lPtr, 4)
End Function
```

Remember declare your own variables BEFORE definition of this subroutines! Or it will cause some strange mistakes (VB suddenly replaced my Exit Sub statement with Exit Function!).

Then I used

```
    If Peek(ArrPtr(SomeArray)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Looks like empty array SomeArray() before ReDim ^_^"
    End If
```

and

```
    Erase SomeArray

    If Peek(ArrPtr(SomeArray)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Looks like empty array SomeArray() after Erase ^_^"
    End If
```

and everything works fine!

Not very simple, but fine.

Thx everybody, I shall learn this chained list named Collection.

Especially thanks for VBForums, they are really geeked ones.